# Nonexistence of Limit Cycle

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

Consider a planar dynamical system described in polar coordinates as
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\dot{\theta}=\Delta - r \sin \theta,\\
\dot{r} = - r + 1 + \cos \theta, 
\end{array}
\right.
$$
where $\Delta$ is a constant such that $|\Delta|< \max_{0\le x\le 2\pi}(1+\cos x)\sin x$.
 I need to show that the system does not have any limit cycle.

Remark: The system has a stable node and a saddle node.

Maybe a better question is that what are the ideas, methods and tricks to prove of nonexistence of limit cycle, especially for planar systems. For example, Dulac- Bendixson is one of them. Is there any other?

Comment: could you please write your original system(In x-y coordinate)?

Comment: Do you allow polycycles, or do you really mean «limit cycle» as a periodic trajectory (i.e. without singularity) ?

Comment: @AliTaghavi You can use a change of variable to convert it to x-y coordinates but in fact its original form is the mentioned above.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier No I just wanna prove that there exist no limit cycle, absorbing(stable) limit cycle. If you know any paper, methods,... all are appreciated.

Comment: What does numerical experimentation suggest ? If there is a limit cycle then it must occur in the closed disk $\{|r|\leq 2\}$. The point is that there is no generic/systematic way to deal with limit cycles, so I'm afraid you're not going to get any definite answer in that respect...

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier: Numerical results show the non-existence of such thing. Now I want to prove it.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier There are various literature on the number of limit cycle. As you may know, one famous Hilbert problem is on this topic, for planar systems described by $\dot {x}=P(x,y),\dot{y} = Q(x,y)$, where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials of $x$ and $y$. The Hilbert problem is whether the number of limit cycles is finite for every such $P$ and $Q$ with degrees bounded with some assumed number. Recently, It is proved for fixed $P$ and $Q$, the number of limit cycles are finite, but generally it is yet an open problem. (Please correct me if I am wrong on Hilbert problem)

Comment: @MohammadKhosravi: you are entirely right. I was only pointing out the fact that the *systematic* study of limit cycle is difficult, and the openess of Hilbert's 16th problem witnesses this. You are referring to the Dulac-Écalle-Ilyashenko theorem, whose proof is very involved and technical. This theorem is valid also for *real analytic* vector fields of the plane. That being said, I'm sure your problem can be solved, and I'll try myself to have a look when I have more time available ;)

Comment: I suggest you use start with something like pplane(http://math.rice.edu/~dfield/dfpp.html), and plot the vector field on the r-theta plane to get a visual feel of the vector field.

Comment: I think I have solved the problem. Thank you all for your interest.

Comment: @MohammadKhosravi: if you indeed solved your problem, you should post a (possibly short) answer to your own question, and accept it.